# PHP preg_match matches

Tags: php, preg-match

I'm trying to get all the matches from string:

```
$string = '[RAND_15]d4trg[RAND_23]';
```

with preg_match like this:

```
$match = array();
preg_match('#\[RAND_.*]#', $string, $match);
```

but after that $match array looks like this:

```
Array ( [0] => [RAND_15]d4trg[RAND_23] )
```

What should I do to get both occurrences as 2 separate elements in $match array? I would like to get result like this:

```
$match[0] = [RAND_15];
$match[1] = [RAND_23];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use ...

```
$match = array();
preg_match_all('#\[RAND_.*?]#', $string, $match);
```

... instead. `?` modifier will make the pattern become 'lazy', matching the shortest possible substring. Without it the pattern will try to cover the maximum distance possible, and technically, `[RAND_15]d4trg[RAND_23]` *does* match the pattern.

Another way is restricting the set of characters to match with negated character class:

```
$match = array();
preg_match_all('#\[RAND_[^]]*]#', $string, $match);
```

This way we won't have to turn the quantifier into a lazy one, as `[^]]` character class will stop matching at the first `]` symbol.

Still, to catch all the matches you should use `preg_match_all` instead of `preg_match`. Here's the [**demo**](http://ideone.com/3MC7Vy) illustrating the difference.